# How to limit the maximum display length of a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL, and I have a column in a table which contains very long text. I want to select this column in a query, but limit its display length.

Something like:

```
   select longcolumn (only 10 chars) from mytable;
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you can do is use PostgreSQL's [substring()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html) method. Either one of the two commands below will work:

```
SELECT substring(longcolumn for 10) FROM mytable;
SELECT substring(longcolumn from 1 for 10) FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 12):

Slightly shorter:

```
SELECT left(longcolumn, 10) from mytable;
```