# How do I set maximum column width in psql?

Tags: string, postgresql, psql, varchar

**How do I truncate multiple long columns in `psql`?** I have multiple columns, some of which are long, and I would like to fit them all easily in one terminal window. `\pset format wrapped` and `\pset columns COLUMNS` appear to work for some, but not all cases. I mostly care about `character varying` columns, and it does not seem to limit their length or wrap them properly. It works for a simple case of 1 string only.

I am aware of `substr()` and of `\x`, but these are suboptimal. I have many columns, so `substr()` on each of them is too repetitive. And tabular output works best for me here, so `\x` is not as easy to view.

Example:

Set pager properly and run `psql`:

```
export PAGER=less
export LESS='-iMSx4 -RSFX -e'
psql -d db_foo
```

Settings work for the simplest case only:

```
db_foo=# \pset format wrapped
Output format is wrapped.
db_foo=# \pset columns 5
Target width is 5.
db_foo=# select '01234456789 01234456789 01234456789' as foo;
 foo 
-----
 012.
.344.
.567.
.89 .
.012.
...
(1 row)

 -- OK, output is truncated.

db_foo=# select baz from table_baz limit 2;       
             baz              
-----------------------------------
 Salmon Lightweight, Galaxy v1.0.0
 Salmon quant Galaxy v0.14.1.2
(2 rows)

-- not OK, output is not truncated.

db_foo=# select '01234456789 01234456789 01234456789' as foo, baz from table_baz limit 2;
                 foo                 |             baz              
-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
 01234456789 01234456789 01234456789 | Salmon Lightweight, Galaxy v1.0.0
 01234456789 01234456789 01234456789 | Salmon quant Galaxy v0.14.1.2
(2 rows)

-- not OK, output is not truncated - even the strings 
-- that were truncated before.
```

I am running macOS 10.14.6, using:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3

less --version
less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)
```

**RELATED:**

[How to limit the maximum display length of a column in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16464468/967621)
[How do I change the max column width in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48481809/967621)
[Is there a way to set the max width of a column when displaying JSONB results in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59330565/967621)
[Is there a way to set the max width of a column when displaying query results in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30272328/967621)

**SEE ALSO:**

[PostgreSQL: Documentation: psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

> `columns`
> Sets the target width for the wrapped format, and also the width limit
> for determining whether output is wide enough to require the pager or
> switch to the vertical display in expanded auto mode. Zero (the
> default) causes the target width to be controlled by the environment
> variable COLUMNS, or the detected screen width if COLUMNS is not
> set. In addition, if columns is zero then the wrapped format only
> affects screen output. If columns is nonzero then file and pipe output
> is wrapped to that width as well.

Comment: The issue is from `\pset wrapped`: "...Note that psql will not attempt to wrap column header titles; therefore, wrapped format behaves the same as aligned if the total width needed for column headers exceeds the target." Do `\pset columns 11` and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are after, but it might be worth taking a look at [pspg](https://github.com/okbob/pspg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is from `\pset wrapped`(described here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)):

> ...Note that psql will not attempt to wrap column header titles; therefore, wrapped format behaves the same as aligned if the total width needed for column headers exceeds the target.

Set the `columns` value to one that exceeds the header title widths.